# Grouping classes in phpdocumentor

Tags: php, phpdocumentor2

I have been asked to use *PHPDocumentor* to generate a developer's code at work. I am pretty sure I put the @package tags in the right position but when I run the  command to generate the documentation the index html document only displays the last generated class file under the class segment on the page even though I ran the command on multiple files.Please help.

edit: I have solved the issue,apparently files have to be parsed together to be grouped in a single html document.Now I have a new problem, is it possible to have the documentation output in PDF format ?

Comment: Uhm, it's quite difficult to help you without see the code :)

Comment: Also add example of final generated documentation.